Byte64 image text not rendering in localhost development environment when setting as image source (React)
I am working on a website where I am getting images from a database. The images are stored as "bytea" variables in a Postgres SQL database. As from all I've researched on stackoverflow and other sources, if the image is correctly encoded (i.e., byte64) and I specify the string as the image (i.e., ) source, it should load correctly.
My image text variable is confirmed to be a string variable, and it is of form "data:image/jpeg;base64,aVZCT1J3MEtHZ29BQUFBTlN.....". I'm pasting my whole React component below. The variable I just mentioned is named "imgTest", and after the data loads, I continue to only see "test image" instead of the photo.
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function Projects() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [initialLoad, setInitialLoad] = useState(true);
    const [projectData, setProjectData] = useState([]);

    const [imgTest, setImgTest] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData(0, 10);
    }, []);

    const loadData = async(offset, limit) => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/projects', { params: { offset, limit } });
            const newData = Array.isArray(response.data) ? response.data.rows : [response.data.rows];
            // Convert byte arrays to Base64 strings
            const processedData = newData.map(item => {
                const updatedItem = { ...item };
          
                if (item.mainphoto && item.mainphoto.data) {
                  const base64Flag = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,';
                  const mainPhotoStr = arrayBufferToBase64(item.mainphoto.data);
                  updatedItem.mainphoto = base64Flag + mainPhotoStr;
                }
          
                if (item.auxphoto1 && item.auxphoto1.data) {
                  const base64Flag = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,';
                  const auxPhotoStr = arrayBufferToBase64(item.auxphoto1.data);
                  updatedItem.auxphoto1 = base64Flag + auxPhotoStr;
                }
          
                return updatedItem;
              });
            setData((prevData) => [...prevData, ...newData]);
            setOffset(offset + limit);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
        setLoading(false);
    };

    const arrayBufferToBase64 = (buffer) => {
        let binary = '';
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        const len = bytes.byteLength;
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }
        return window.btoa(binary);
      };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (data.length > 0 && data[0]) {
            ////////////////////
            const base64Flag = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,';
            const imageString = base64Flag + arrayBufferToBase64(data[0][0].auxphoto1['data']);
            // console.log('image String',imageString);
            setImgTest(imageString);
            // console.log('image test',imgTest);
            /////////////////////

            const projectData = data.map((item, index) => (
                <div className='project' key={index} >
                    {item[0].clientname}
                    {item[0].clienttag1}
                    {item[0].clienttag2}
                    {item[0].clienttag3}
                    {/* {item[0].mainphoto && <img src={item[0].mainphoto} alt="Project Main" />} */}

                </div>
            ));
            setProjectData(projectData);
        }
      }, [data]);

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log('imgTest', imgTest);
      }, [imgTest]);

    const handleScroll = () => {
        if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop === document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
            loadData(offset, initialLoad ? 10 : 50);
            setInitialLoad(false);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }, [offset]);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="projects">

                {/* Image below will not load. Only shows alt text */}
                {data.length > 0 ?  <img src={imgTest} alt="test image" /> : 'Not Yet'}

            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Projects;

Any thoughts or direction would be appreciated!

You don’t seem to do anything with processedData

Yes, you can ignore for now. Ultimately the image will be a part of processedData but I'm trying to fix the image rendering issue first, so I understand the problem to update as part of processedData

Most likely, the image data is corrupted during transfer from the server to the client. It isn’t clear how the data is transmitted in the response, but you can’t embed arbitrary binary data in a JSON response. It also looks like the arrayBufferToBase64 function isn’t actually implementing a base64 encoding. Your best bet might be to base64-encode the images on the server side rather than in the client. Maybe this is already happening and the client side needs to change to handle it correctly. Please include the server-side API code in the question as well.

It would also be helpful to include an example response in JSON format (assuming that the server is sending JSON).

@TimMoore You are correct. It was getting corrupted in transmission. Thanks for the comment!
